# How to stop an ngrok tunnel?

Tags: command, ngrok

I tried command `killall ngrok`, but I get `'killall' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
Shouldn't `killall` be coming with the ngrok? I can't find any reference to that issue on Internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
taskkill /IM ngrok.exe /F
```

command in cmd will kill ngrok

Comment: I got ```ERROR: The process "ngrok.exe" not found.```

Comment: Aren't you running ngrok with ngrok.exe?

Comment: When I run ```ngrok.exe http 8080``` I get that the tunnel is up and online. I thing it means I am

Comment: Can you go to 127.0.0.1:4040 and see if your ngrok is running, or if it is another process using that port

Comment: I get that it's ngrok, but once I exit the ngrok command line Windows I got from  ```ngrok.exe http 8080``` , 127.0.0.1:4040 becomes not accessible anymore. Is ```ngrok.exe http 8080```the command that starts the tunnel and stops it when I press Ctrl+C?

Comment: Yes it is you should exit it with Ctrl+C